# LUKS on boot with FIDO "or" Password

Tags: luks, fido-u2f

I've managed to unlock my `LUKS` partation on boot with a `FIDO2` key

My `crypttab` is

```
myvolume /dev/sda5 - fido2-device=auto
```

But I still keep a `LUKS` key slot with a password (my `fido` key is always on my dock, not my laptop). Now my boot sequence fails if the key is not connected because it always wants the key PIN number.

With the `FIDO` Pam module, I get asked the `PIN+touch` only if the key is connected, otherwise it falls back to just asking for the password.

**QUESTION:**

Is it possible to have a similar behavior when unloking `LUKS` from my boot sequence?